# Routing error in Controller_specs in active_admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, activeadmin

I've set up some specs to test my active admin controllers.

```
it "assigns the requested blog to @blog" do
  @blog = FactoryGirl.create(:blog)
  get :show, id: @blog
  assigns(:blog).should eq(@blog) 
end
```

When I run this spec file separately it's all green, but when I run all my specs I get this error:

```
Failure/Error: get :show, :id => @blog
         ActionView::Template::Error:
           No route matches {:id=>#<User id: nil, role: nil, phone: nil, name: nil, firm_id: nil, hourly_rate: nil, loginable_type: nil, loginable_id: nil, loginable_token: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, avatar_file_name: nil, avatar_content_type: nil, avatar_file_size: nil, avatar_updated_at: nil, email: "", encrypted_password: "", reset_password_token: nil, reset_password_sent_at: nil, remember_created_at: nil, sign_in_count: 0, current_sign_in_at: nil, last_sign_in_at: nil, current_sign_in_ip: nil, last_sign_in_ip: nil>, :controller=>"admin/blogs", :action=>"edit", :format=>nil} missing required keys: [:id]
```

Any idea what's wrong?

Comment: what is the relationship of blog to other models?

Comment: You might want to try capybara's `save_and_open_page` as discussed in http://jeffkreeftmeijer.com/2010/ever-heard-of-capybaras-save_and_open_page-method/ to see what you've got.

Comment: I'd guess one of your `link_to` calls on the Blog's show page is unable to generate a URL without a user available.

Comment: @dax. Blog does not have any relationship to other models. Author is just set as a string.

Comment: @PeterAlfvin. I don't see how `save_and_open_page` would help. The specs works in one scenario but not in an other scenario. There is something funky about the tests. Adding `save_and_open_page would` just add complexity

Comment: @CMaresh. Active_admin generates this link_to under the hood. Is works when I click in the browser and when I run the spec separately. It just does not work when I run the whole test suite.